# Dropbox Python API: File size detection may have failed

Tags: python, api, dropbox

I'm attempting to upload a text file to Dropbox using this code:

```
def uploadFile(file):
    f = open('logs/%s.txt' % file)
    response = client.put_file('/%s.txt' % file, f)
    print "Uploaded log file %s" % file
```

Connecting to dropbox works perfectly fine, it's just when I upload files I recieve this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox_python_sdk-1.5.1-py2.7.egg\dropbox
\client.py", line 352, in put_file
    return self.rest_client.PUT(url, file_obj, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox_python_sdk-1.5.1-py2.7.egg\dropbox
\rest.py", line 265, in PUT
    return cls.IMPL.PUT(*n, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox_python_sdk-1.5.1-py2.7.egg\dropbox
\rest.py", line 211, in PUT
    return self.request("PUT", url, body=body, headers=headers, raw_response=raw
_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dropbox_python_sdk-1.5.1-py2.7.egg\dropbox
\rest.py", line 174, in request
    raise util.AnalyzeFileObjBug(clen, bytes_read)
dropbox.util.AnalyzeFileObjBug:
Expected file object to have 18 bytes, instead we read 17 bytes.
File size detection may have failed (see dropbox.util.AnalyzeFileObj)
```

Google has given me no help with this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you are a victim of newline unification. The file object reports a file size of 18 bytes (`"abcdefghijklmnop\r\n"`) but you read only 17 bytes (`"abcdefghijklmnop\n"`).

Open the file in binary mode to avoid this:

```
f = open('logs/%s.txt' % file, 'rb')
```

> The default is to use text mode, which may convert `'\n'` characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading.

Comment: Thank you very much, I never would have figured that out.